# error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'something'

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am trying to make some code in c++ using some features of c++11. I am using vectors, lists and so on...

The contentious part of my code is being presented below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
//#include <Winbase.h>

using namespace std;

// A struct describing a product.
typedef struct Products
{
    string category;
    string name;
    float price;
} Product;

inline void scenario1(int num_cashiers)
{
    vector<Product> products; // It is a vector(a pseudo-second dimension) of products which will be used for each customer
    vector<vector<Product>> customers; // A vector containing all customers
    vector<vector<vector<Product>>> cashiers(num_cashiers); // A vector describing the supermarket cashiers declaring a queue of customers for each cashier
    double start = GetTickCount(); // It will be used for counting 10 secs until next update
    vector<int> total_products(num_cashiers); // A vector keeping the total number of products of each queue
    list<string> categories; // A list containing all the categories of the products
list<float> categories_prices; // A list containing all category prices
map<string,float> statistics; // A map that keeps the statistical report of the supermarket. It keeps the name of each category and the total amount having been paid by customers for products of this category
string want_new_customers;
short number_new_customers;
short number_products;
string new_answer;
short pos_min_cashier;
string seeQueue;
int select_cashier;
string seeAvgTime;
string seeStatistics;

while (true)
{
    double current_time = GetTickCount() - start; // We are taking each and every second.

    // Update every 10 secs (=10000msecs)
    if (current_time >= 10000) //
    {
        cout << "Would you like to add some customers?(Y or N)" << endl;
        cin >> want_new_customers;
        if (want_new_customers == "Y" || want_new_customers == "y")
        {
            cout << "How many customers would you like to add?" << endl;
            cin >> number_new_customers;
            customers.reserve(number_new_customers);
            for (int &i : customers) //HERE IS THE FIRST LINE I AM GETTING THE ERROR
            {
                cout << "Give some necessary information about customer no. " << i << endl;
                cout << "Give the number of products he/she bought" << endl;
                cin >> number_products;
                customers[i].reserve(number_products);
                Products products[number_new_customers][number_products];
                for (int &j : products) //HERE IS THE SECOND ONE
                {
                    cout << "Give the category of the product no. " << j << endl;
                    cin >> products[i][j].category;
                    cout << "Give the name of the product no. " << j << endl;
                    cin >> products[i][j].name;
                    cout << "Give the price of the product no. " << j << endl;
                    cin >> products[i][j].price;
                }
            }
        }//AND THE CODE GOES ON
```

I have to make clear that customers and products are vectors which have been declared beforehand. **Also, the something name is 'std::vector' for the first line the error occurs and 'Products*'
for the second one.**

I am afraid of something being wrong with my for-loop method. I tried to do a for_each loop or a range for-loop in my way as far as I can understand. Something may be wrong with referencing of i through the size of the vector customers(of j through the size of products vector respectively).

What is wrong with my loops and how could I fix it?

Comment: Evidently, those loops aren't doing what you expect them to. Look up how to use a ranged-for loop.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You seem to have your types mixed up. What is `customers`? You loop over it like it was a container holding `int`s. But then you call `customers[i].reserve()`, now it looks like `customers` is actually a container holding `vector`s or something.

Comment: What is `customers`?

Comment: @chris I searched for it and I found this way of writing a ranged for-loop.

Comment: @immibis I said in the post what the customers is.

Comment: @TaksiarxisMitropoulos range based for retrieves each element of the container, not it's index. `for (std::vector<Product>& customer : customers)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to have a Customer class which holds vector of products. Also a Cashier class to hold your customer. Say you have a vector of customers.

```
std::vector<Customer> customers;
```

There are two ways in which to use a for loop to access elements iteratively

```
for (int i = 0; i < customers.size; i++)
{
    customers[i]; //access element
}
```

OR

```
for (Customer customer: customers)
{
    customer;//access element
}
```

If you want to use it in vector of vectors

```
for (int i = 0; i < customers.size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < customers[i].size; j++)
    {
        customers[i][j]; //access element
     }
}
```

Comment: I edited my post..Take a look again now please in order to edit your answer, if necessary..

Comment: I solved the errors. I just wrote for (auto i : customers), similarly for the inner loop.

Comment: auto works because it automatically stores the correct data. auto stores a copy and auto& will store a reference

Comment: I know, this is why I did it..but I am not sure what is right. the former or the latter you said. Also, I am coming up with a new problem, no match for operator [ ]. It does not "accept" neither the customers[i] nor products[i][j].name and other similar tokens. Why? Is this perhaps a non-acceptable form for vectors?

Comment: When you are doing customers [i] where "i" is a vector<Product> in your code, the result is definitely an error. The [] only accepts an index such as an int.  The former answer I provided is using a class Customer. The later answer I have provided after your edit works for vector <vector<Product>>. I would suggest looking up how to use vectors.

Comment: Also checkout http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for for ranged for loop